# Grails 3: Best place for Java/Groovy Configuration clases?

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security

The project layout is pretty straightforward for the basic stuff, but I'm looking to write some code for my security layer, generating and authenticating tokens and the like, and I'm not sure where that belongs.

For example, I want to create a class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to authorize requests. Where does this belong? The init folder? Services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not coding Grails artefacts (ex. controllers, domain classes) then src/main/groovy is a good place for them.